# Is a *surface*-line intersection rational if the line passes through another rational point on the surface?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, diophantine-equations, rational-numbers

I've seen some interesting geometric interpretations of Diophantine equations before. For instance, if we wish to find Pythagorean triples, we can take $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$, divide through by $c^2$, and get $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, which is the unit circle. We then choose an obvious rational point on the circle, e.g., $(-1, 0)$.

Now, any line with a rational finite slope that passes through $(-1,0)$ will intersect the circle at another point with rational coordinates. Then $a$ and $b$ are the numerators of the coordinates, and $c$ is the denominator (after bringing them to a common denominator).

Of course, something similar happens on elliptic curves as well.

I've been looking into a similar problem, but it requires three-variables--and therefore a surface more complex than the unit circle. It's also a cubic:

$$z^3 - z = xy(x^2-y^2)$$

(This is in relation to the order-3 magic square of squares problem.) If a line passes through one rational point on the surface, must any other intersections also be rational points? Or is there a restriction of some sort?

Comment: Note that your surface contains entire lines, for example $x=z=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the other two points need not be rational. In general they will be defined over a quadratic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ and conjugate.

Comment: OK, here's my difficulty: what does a quadratic extension over $\mathbb{Q}$ *mean*? If it really means "You need to understand field theory to understand the actual question you're asking," then I can handle that, but I'm not sure when I'll actually get to fields in self-teaching. :)

Comment: That means that each coordinate of these points satisfies a quadratic equation with rational coefficients and the same discriminant.

Comment: Thanks. I think I may have ended up asking an XY question. From what I can tell looking at more info, if the equation is a cubic (i.e., an elliptic curve), we require two rational points that also intersect the curve a third time.